# API Call to S3 Timing Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Working with a tool that scans infrastructure within an AWS environment via API calls at the moment.  It uses an AWS IAM Access Key to authenticate to AWS, then assumes an IAM Role with the necessary `Read` permissions within an account.  Excerpt from the role actions:

```
- "s3:Get*"
- "s3:List*"
```

All other service API calls (EC2, IAM, etc.) are functioning as expected and returning data, except for S3.  During any S3 API call, like `ListBuckets`, we get the following response:

```
Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Now, I imagine since S3 is a global construct in AWS it could be the result of different network routing but am not exactly sure what specifically to look at.  If we ran into permissions problems previously with other services, we would get an explicit `Access Denied` error returned to us.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this code running inside an AWS VPC? Is your VPC configured with any VPC endpoints? Do you have a firewall (or AWS security groups) that block S3?

Comment: Yes, I wonder whether there is a VPC Endpoint that is redirecting all requests to S3 in that specific region, such that calls to S3 in other regions are being blocked. From where is that 'tool' running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back on this.  The issue was with an internal firewall that handled calls to S3 differently and gave an explicit deny.  Once the allow rule was in place, calls to S3 were functioning as expected.

For others dealing with this problem, we still have intermittent issues with calls to S3 because the IP range that AWS uses for S3 API calls can vary.